# Collapse fieldset

Tags: admin, forms

I have an admin module with an edit form, that has two fieldsets. On opening the page both fieldset are open by default and there is no option for the user to close either of them. How do I have one closed by default when the page is rendered?

my code

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Edit_Form    
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form

$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
        'legend'    => $this->__('Module information'),
        'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
    ));

    //set the container that holds form information
    $fieldset2 = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset2', array(
        'legend'    => $this->__('A pointless second blue bar'),
        'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
    ));

...additional code to create fields...
```

I looked into `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Fieldset` and found `_addExtraJs()` and `_getCollapseState()` but this does not seem to be extended by `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form` and im guessing using instaniating that object is not the best way to achieve my goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try expanded? As in the `system.xml`?

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
    'legend'    => $this->__('Module information'),
    'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
    'expanded'  => true, // open
));

//set the container that holds form information
$fieldset2 = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset2', array(
    'legend'    => $this->__('A pointless second blue bar'),
    'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
    'expanded'  => false, // closed
));
```